# How to fill blank country column with country name in pandas python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have data frame columns like language, region and country. In that data frame using language column to fill the country with country name.

My input is:

```
language      region         country

english        a            canada
chinese        b            china
english        a            usa
japanese       a            japan
english        a            usa
portugese      b            portugal
english        a            null
```

In above data frame, I want to fill the null country name with by using country names based on count which countries are using English.
Let's suppose USA count has 2 and Canada count has 1. So, USA has highest count then we have to fill the USA country name in null place.

Required output should be:

```
language      region         country

english        a            canada
chinese        b            china
english        a            usa
japanese       a            japan
english        a            usa
portugese      b            portugal
english        a            usa
```

For above required output I used below code snippet. But it is not working. Can anyone help me for above required output data frame.

```
df.loc[df['language']=='english' & df['region']='ap' & df['country'].value_counts()[df['country'].value_counts() == df['country'].value_counts().max()]
```

In above code snippet i must need to be use  df.loc[df['language']=='english' & df['region']='ap'.after that i have to find highest country count based on AP region and fill blank country as with highest country count country.

Answer (score 2):

Assume your `null` is `NaN` or `None`. If it is string `null`, You need pre-process it to `NaN`

```
df = df.where(df.ne('null')) # doing this step if your `null` is string `null`

m = df.country.isna()
m1 = df.language.eq('english')

df.loc[m & m1, 'country'] = df.loc[m1, 'country'].mode()[0]

Out[194]:
    language region   country
0    english      a    canada
1    chinese      b     china
2    english      a       usa
3   japanese      a     japan
4    english      a       usa
5  portugese      b  portugal
6    english      a       usa
```

Answer (score 2):

A more generalized solution would be to `map` and `fillna`

```
d = df.groupby('language').country.apply(lambda s: s.mode()[0]).to_dict() 
df['country'] = df.country.fillna(df.language.map(d))
```

```
    language region   country
0    english      a    canada
1    chinese      b     china
2    english      a       usa
3   japanese      a     japan
4    english      a       usa
5  portugese      b  portugal
6    english      a       usa
```